# How to remove sql instance

Tags: sql, sql-server

My problem is that I can't remove instance. Here is an example right now I have two instances

1. `SQLEXPRESS`
2. `SQLEXPRESS2012`

I have SQL Server 2012, in order to remove instance I go to `Control Panel -> Add and remove programs ->` choose `Microsoft Sql Server` and after that I will get to UI where I can do different manipulations with different stuff.

In this UI I am able to delete `SQLEXPRESS2012` but I can't select `SQLEXPRESS`. Also when I am in SQL Server Management Studio I can connect to `SQLEXPRESS2012` server, but can't connect to  `SQLEXPRESS` server it gives me error:40 and 2.

My guess the instance not exist but some where it is in register. Any suggestions how to delete instance without going to  control panel-> add and remove programs -> choose Microsoft Sql Server. Thank you for your time

Comment: i encounter same problem, what i did was i reinstall sql server and remove the instance name during installation

Comment: Yes, the installation exe will allow you to remove instances.

Comment: I dont know where you are able to do that. is it in SQL server Setup? Because in Installation type I can only select SQLEXPRESS2012 in dropdown menu even In a row with Instance Name, I can see two instances.

Comment: Yes, but you have to run the right version of setup. For example, the 2012 UI will not correctly identify and allow you to uninstall a 2008 instance.

Comment: I see I will try to get 2008 and see if that setup will do the magic

Comment: I was just using 2008 as an example. I have no idea what version your `SQLEXPRESS` instance is. You could also just pretend it doesn't exist and disable the service, as I suggest in my answer... other than preventing you from re-using the name `SQLEXPRESS` and occupying a bit of disk space, I can't see what harm it would cause.

Comment: I installed server 2008 in my control panel->add remove programs-> I see Microsoft SQL SErver Native Client it does not let me to delete instance. Even when I go threw setup it does not give me any option to remove instance .... thank you for your help

Comment: yeah 2008 it was now I can select and manipulate with SQLEXPRESS instance I just cant find option to delete it, not in SQL server setup no in SQL server Installation Center not in control panael add and remove programs :(

Answer (score 12):

Verify that there is really only one entry in Add/Remove Programs for SQL Server. I have multiple, one for every version of SQL Server I have installed:

> [image: List of SQL Server versions in add/remove programs]

If there really is only one entry in Control Panel, then it's possible you have some kind of corrupted install. [Microsoft has a guide here for 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909967), which may still be helpful in more modern versions (it's unclear from your question which version the old instance is). I've written about [removing an expired instance of SQL Server before](https://sqlblog.org/2010/10/25/fun-with-software-uninstalling-sql-server-2008-r2-evaluation-edition); this would be similar. Find the GUIDs listed under Uninstall in the following registry key (this may take some manual work) that do *not* involve SQL Server 2012:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
```

For example, here is the entry for the 2008 database engine services on my machine:

> [image]

For each one, copy the display name (in a comment) and the GUID file (behind `msiexec /x`) to a `.bat` file, e.g.

```
REM SQL Server 2008 Database Engine Services
msiexec /x "{32445783-54FC-4AA7-A51A-3B528E8A5E3B}"
```

The number of entries you'll have will depend on the version, edition, selected features, etc. Once you've copied them all, save the `.bat` file and double-click it. Depending on the order of the entries in the file, you may get some "unexpected error" results, or potentially errors like this one:

[image]

If you get any of the former, you should run the batch file again.

Of course, if you don't want to risk any damage to your system, you could always just disable the SQLEXPRESS instance's services using SQL Server Configuration Manager, and pretend it's not installed.

Comment: Thank you for informative response , if you being so kind could you provide the link for proper 2008 server, I think the Microsoft SQL server 2008 this is what I need to have in my control panel in oreder to remove instance, I installed 2008 express but in my control panel I am getting Microsoft server 2008 native client. right now I am also trying to clean up register. thank you

Comment: Nevr mind I cleaned the registry and it did the job , thank you

Comment: Upvote for 'disabling the instance'. I was about to try something more drastic...

Comment: Just as a note here, if you have more than one SQL server install, ie, 2012, 2014, 2016, or whatever, some entries will remain in the AddRemove Programs listing for backward compatibility. Once you blow away all of the 2008 Uninstall registry entries, you may need to go back and REPAIR your functioning SQL install, say 2012, in order to maintain backward compatibility.